# Java - data structure for infix calculator

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, calculator

I want to build infix calculator. Approach that I choose is parsing input in tree with operators in nodes and operands in leafs, then traverse tree from bottom to top (from high priority operators to lower).

Example of tree:

```
                         (12 + 8) / 2 - 5

                                –
                              /   \
                            '/'    5
                            / \
                           +   2    
                          / \  
                         12  8
```

First: I am pretty new in Java, what data structure should I choose or maybe I need to create new class with my own tree implementation?

And second: what is best way to handle brackets priorities?

Comment: The best way is probably to write simple [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammar and use it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a small class hierarchy with `Operand` being subclassed into `Operation` and `Literal`. An `Operation` has one field for the operator (best: an enum) and two `Operand` fields.

The parser can create `Operation` and `Literal` objects and store their references into the containing `Operation`.

Parentheses disappear, since the resulting tree (as in your Q) will be structured according to the priority: either as grouped by parentheses, then by operator priority and finally left-to-right.

You can write a simple recursive-descent parser, no need to set up antlr for this little academic exercise.

**Later** Here is the BNF of a simple grammar for arithmetic expressions:

```
<expression> ::= <term> | <term> <addop> <expression>
<term>       ::= <factor> | <term> <mulop> <factor>
<factor>     ::= <constant> | (" <expression> ")"
<constant>   ::= <digit> | <digit> <constant>
<addop>      ::= "+" | "-"
<mulop>      ::= "*" | "/"
<digit>      ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
```

A recursive descent parser consists of methods parsing the non-terminals by looking for the terminals (parentheses, operators, digits) and composing the non-terminals according to one of the alternatives. On success, a `Literal` or `Operation` object is returned, to be incorporated into the object composed by the caller.